# 一部屋一部屋 Meaning and reading

Tags: meaning, readings, counters

I'm having some trouble with the following sentence:

> 一部屋一部屋が大きいのだろう、部屋のドアの間隔が広かった。

What's the meaning of the double "一部屋"? I think it's supposed to be each/every room, but I'm not sure. Also, is it read as "ひとへやひとへや"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

一部屋一部屋 is read as ひとへやひとへや, and means "each one of the rooms". Here 部屋 is used as the counter for rooms (一部屋【ひとへや】, 二部屋【ふたへや】, 三部屋【さんへや】/三部屋【みへや】, ...).

Generally, yes, this is a pattern that means "each ～" or "every ～".

> - このプロジェクトではひとりひとりが重要だ。
>     In this project, each one of us is important.
> - 彼の一言一言【ひとことひとこと】が気に障る。
>     Every word of his annoys me.
> - ひとつひとつ見ていきましょう。
>     Let's take a look at them one by one.
> - 一回一回【いっかいいっかい】説明しないと彼女は理解しない。
>     She doesn't understand it unless I explain every time.

Comment: Note that the reduplicated words are counted as single compounds: ひとへやひとへや{LHHHHHLL}, not ひとへや{LHLL}ひとへや{LHLL}.